# pointer in C function needs unsigned type array, but my array is signed

Tags: c, pointers, unsigned

I have a function as follows that processes the information contained in an array of type unsigned char:

```c
unsigned char LRCsimple(unsigned char *p, createLRC , unsigned char length)
{

}
```

Works great for mostly unsigned char arrays.

Now, I have a signed array and when I use such a function and it works very well, but I have a warning when compiling the code:

```
> ../src/apptcpipserver.c:102:9: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of 'LRCsimple' differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
         if (0x01 == LRCsimple(apptcpipserverData.cRxedData,0x00,(apptcpipserverData.cRxedData[0x02] - 0x02)))
```

If I want to avoid this warning, I think the optimal solution is to create a function similar to the one above, but for a signed array, as follows:

```c
unsigned char signedLRCsimple(char *p, createLRC , unsigned char length)
{

}
```

Or is there something else I can do to avoid that warning message?

Comment: Please don't use snippets for languages that aren't JavaScript. It serves no purpose and even harms readability somewhat.

Comment: Depending on what that function does, a template might be better.

Comment: Depending on what is stored in the string and how it is used, you _might_ be able to use a typecast.

Comment: @Beta: There are no templates in C.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: [facepalm] You're right.

Comment: Edit the question to explain what the function does. The file name (containing “tcp” and “ip” and the routine name (with “LRC” possibly for longitudinal redundancy check) suggestion the routine might be working solely with the bytes of the buffer for network transmission purposes, just as raw bits without regard to their meaning to the caller. In this case, the data should generally be passed as `void *` or `const void *`. Internally, the routine would convert the pointer to `unsigned char *` or `const unsigned char *` to work with it…

Comment: … On the other hand, if the routine performs some function based on the meaning of the data, such as its values as `int` types, as characters in a character set, as floating-point data, and so on, then it generally ought to take the data as a pointer to its actual type.

Comment: If the functions works perfectly with your data (you test it in depth, don't you?) and you just want to get rid of the warning, you can simply cast `apptcpipserverData.cRxedData` to `unsigned char *`. Since this is explicitly in the source, any reader will notice this special case. -- BTW, does the function change any value pointed to? If not, why is the parameter not marked as pointing to `const unsigned char`?

Comment: Unqualified `char` is a different type to both `unsigned char` and `signed char`, but behaves identically to one of those two. *In your environment* that happens to be `signed char`.

*Always* qualify your `char`s if they represent small integers; *Never* qualify them if they represent characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strict aliasing rule allows `unsigned char` and `char` alias. Therefore you should be able reuse `LRCsimple` for processing `char*`.

Therefore `signedLRCsimple` could be implemented as:

```
unsigned char signedLRCsimple(char *p, createLRC xxx, unsigned char length)
{
   return LRCsimple((unsigned char*)p, xxx, length);
}
```

To avoid forcing client to change their code to use `signedLRCsimple` you could use *generic selection* introduced in C11 in form of `_Generic`. Typically it is used to select a function pointer basing on the type of first argument of `_Generic`.

```
#define LRCsimple(p, xxx, length)          \
  _Generic((p), unsigned char*: LRCsimple, \
                char *: signedLRCsimple)(p, xxx, length)
```

Whenever `LRCsimple` is called the generic selection selects between `LRCsimple` for `unsigned char*` and `signedLRCsimple` for `char*`. For other types an error is raised.

Comment: C’s aliasing rules may mean the language will support this, but it does not mean it is a good idea. We should find out what OP’s routine is doing and give advice for that particular situation.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, that is why I used word "could". OP can decide if this wrapper is appropriate. I guess it would work because the only issue OP complains about are the warnings

Comment: Writing code for the purpose of silencing warnings, rather than for the purpose of getting the code right, is a source of bugs. It is bad programming practice.